# How to get the average value after grouping by columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `df`, and I want to get the average usage `time` of different `apps` by different `gender` groups.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'user':[2,3,4,4,5,5],'gender':[0,0,1,1,1,1],
'app':['k','k','k','k','s','s'],'time':[6,10,10,6,3,1]})
```

`Input:`

```
  app  gender  time  user
0   k    0     6     2
1   k    0    10     3
2   k    1    10     4
3   k    1     6     4
4   s    1     3     5
5   s    1     1     5
```

For `app k`, the total time for the `gender 0` group to use `app k` is `16 (10 + 6 )`, so the average usage time `0_k` is `8.0`.

And the total time for the `gender 1` group to use `app k` is `16 (10 + 6 + 0 + 0)`, so the average usage time `1_k` is `4.0`.

`Expected:`

```
dict = {'0_k': 8.0, '0_s': 0, '1_k': 4.0, '1_s': 1.0}
```

Comment: For `gender 1` group to use app `k` is not -  `16 (10 + 6) / 2 = 8` ?

Comment: I just want to get the `gender` group to use different `app`. As you see, `gender 1` group has a total of four people.

Comment: @rosefun Check if my solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC I think you need:

```
df['new_col'] = df.gender.astype(str)+'_'+df.app
df['Average'] = df.groupby(['gender','app'])['time'].transform('sum')/\
                df.groupby(['gender'])['time'].transform('count')

print(df)
   user  gender app  time new_col  Average
0     2       0   k     6     0_k      8.0
1     3       0   k    10     0_k      8.0
2     4       1   k    10     1_k      4.0
3     4       1   k     6     1_k      4.0
4     5       1   s     3     1_s      1.0
5     5       1   s     1     1_s      1.0

d = dict(df[['new_col','Average']].values)

print(d)
{'0_k': 8.0, '1_k': 4.0, '1_s': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(df.groupby(["app", "gender"]).sum()/df.groupby(["gender"]).count()).time


app  gender
k    0         8.0
     1         4.0
s    1         1.0
```

To trasform it to a dictionary:

```
dict = (df.groupby(["app", "gender"]).sum()/df.groupby(["gender"]).count()).time.to_dict()

{('k', 0): 8.0, ('s', 1): 2.0, ('k', 1): 8.0}
```